# ending "why not ... " with a question mark or period

Tags: punctuation

If you were writing EFL materials, would you end the following sentence with a question mark or a period?

> Why not search for a recipe online, buy some ingredients, and make a cake of your dreams?

Answer (score 4):

The correct ending for a question is a question mark, and a suggestion framed as a  "why not" question is no exception.